# Using curl and xargs to get individual sitemaps

Tags: curl, sed, grep, sitemap, xargs

I'm trying to use this curl command to download a bunch of gzipped xml sitemaps that contain product urls.

The default behaviour of it goes to the robots.txt file, finds the sitemap file that contains all the urls for the individual sitemaps, uncompresses them, then find the  in the individual sitemaps that contain the url for all the individual products.

What I'd like to do instead is download each individual sitemap (over 400) to its own file and then manipulate those sitemaps on my local machine.

```
curl -N https://www.example.com/robots.txt |
    sed -n 's/^Sitemap: \(.*\)$/\1/p' |
    sed 's/\r$//g' |
    xargs -n1 curl -N |
    grep -oP '<loc>\K[^<]*' |
    xargs -n1 curl -N |
    gunzip |
    grep -oP '<loc>\K[^<]*' |
    gzip > \
    somefile.txt.gz
```

Right now it puts all the data in one file - which is just too large. I've tried a few things like this and eventually came up with this:

```
curl -N https://www.example.com/robots.txt |
    sed -n 's/^Sitemap: \(.*\)$/\1/p' |
    xargs -n1 curl -N |
    grep -oP '<loc>\K[^<]*' |
    sort > carid-list-of-compressed-sitemaps.txt
```

which works nicely and gives me a list of the gzipped xml sitesmaps but I can't quite figure out how to get the individual uncompressed sitemaps that have the product urls in them.

So basically I want to download all the individual product sitemaps that have the individual product urls in them.

Comment: Can you show 5 lines of `carid-list-of-compressed-sitemaps.txt` and why looping over this file with `... curl .. | gunzip ..| grep .. | gzip` doesn't work?

Comment: @WalterA - I'm not sure I understand your question... the robots.txt file points to a sitemap index file which over 400 xml.gz urls. I want to be able to download each sitemap into its own file locally.  The original script does work, it simply puts all the urls into 1 massive file.

Comment: You said your second command works. So that will generate a `carid-list-of-compressed-sitemaps.txt`. The next step would be something like `while IFS= read -r sitegz; do ... done < carid-list-of-compressed-sitemaps.txt`, and handle each sitemap and change the outputfile for each sitemap in the loop.

Comment: @WalterA - Ah ok, now I'm starting to get it... I'm a newbie with bash. If you can put this into an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use 2 steps. I deleted the `$` in the first `sed` command, because `.*` is already matching until the end of the line.
I removed the gzip, that was not needed with my test site.

```
caridlist="carid-list-of-compressed-sitemaps.txt"
curl -sN https://www.example.com/robots.txt |
    sed -n 's/^Sitemap: \(.*\)/\1/p' |
    xargs -n1 curl -sN |
    grep -oP '<loc>\K[^<]*' > "${carid-list-of-compressed-sitemaps.txt}" 

filenumber=1
urlinfile=1
while IFS= read -r site_url; do
    curl -sN "${site_url}"|
    grep -oP '<loc>\K[^<]*' > somefile_${filenumber}.txt
    ((urlinfile++))
    if ((urlinfile==10)); then
       ((filenumber++))
       urlinfile=1
    fi
done < "${carid-list-of-compressed-sitemaps.txt}"
```